# C# WinForms - Import Data to Listbox from XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, import

XML Code

```
-<RegionBox>

<Regions>fdzg</Regions>

<Regions>asgfasd</Regions>

<Regions>sdfadga</Regions>

<Regions>adsfgsfha</Regions>

</RegionBox>
```

How I save XML

```
 XElement element = new XElement("RegionBox");
        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("Regions", item));


            //DataRow listRow = ds.Tables["RegionBox"].NewRow();
            //listRow["List"] = listBox1.Items;
            //Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        XDocument document = new XDocument();
        document.Add(element);
        document.Save("XMLFile2.xml");
```

I want to be able to import the data back into the List box
currently I've tried

```
            ds.ReadXml("XMLFile2.xml");
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["RegionBox"].Columns.Count; i++)
            listBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables["Regions"].Rows[0][i].ToString());
        setImage.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath.Text);
        }
```

and

```
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml");
        var items = (from i in xmlDoc.Descendants("Regions")
                     select new { Item = i.Element("Regions").Value }).ToList();
                     listBox1.DataSource = items;
```

But I can't seem to get it to import the information... though I have been successful with getting either the first item or the last item but only one and not all of the items can be imported

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:: just after posting this I found I continued my search and then found one that worked

```
            XElement element = XElement.Load("XMLFile2.xml");
        foreach (XElement item in element.Elements("Regions"))
        listBox1.Items.Add(item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `select new { Item = i.Element("Regions").Value })` is wrong,because the parameter `i` is already the element of `Regions` ,so you just need to change the code like `select new { Item = i.Value })`
2. I dont't know whether you have set the `DisplayMember`,maybe you should to add this code `listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item";`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will make much sense, but with regards to reading xml data and then displaying it -

```
XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader("../../Products.xml");
        xReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(xReader);
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter product...");
        string product = Console.ReadLine();
        XmlNodeList xNodeList = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Products/Product");

        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodeList)
        {
            if (xNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine(xNode.NodeType.ToString() + " : " + xNode.Name + " =" + xNode.FirstChild.InnerText);
                if (xNode.FirstChild.InnerText == product)
                {
                    string name = xNode.FirstChild.InnerText;
                    string price = xNode.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText;
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name + "... Price: R" + price);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Price");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

With the XML file being Products.xml -

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <name>Bread</name>
    <price>10</price>
</Product>
<Product>
    <name>Milk</name>
    <price>20</price>
</Product>
<Product>
    <name>Coke</name>
    <price>18</price>
</Product>
<Product>
    <name>BarOne</name>
    <price>7</price>
</Product>
```

Some explaining:

The XmlTextReader can only be accessed once you add the using System.Xml; namespace, once you initialize a XmlTextReader (xReader), you can load it with an .xml file, mine is Products.xml which is found 2 folders back from the debug folder, hence the ("../../") - skipping two folders back, which is actually the root folder but 2 folders out of the "debug" folder.

The xmlNodeList selects nodes, what I did there is only select up to Product, so the next node is name, and the next sibling node after that is price.

I'm sure the foreach loop is self explanatory, 
the first if statement makes sure the node is an element, 
the second if statement checks if the product name (bread, milk, etc) matches that what the user inputted in the beginning. If it does, then a string is made, and named "name", because the first child is the name, and we want the name's node value, so innerText will get that for us.

To get the price, we just say xNode.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText, this will move from the  to the next node, which is  which is what we want.

Hope this helps?